# Azure DevOps (VSTS) Can not create a public project

Tags: azure-devops

The **Public** option is disabled in visibility section of create project page. When I move the mouse over the info icon of public option, it says that: *Your enterprise is preventing you from selecting this option*.

As I know, `Enterprise` in VSTS means the account that is currently selected, and each enterprise can contain many organizations.

My currently selected enterprise is **Microsoft Account**, and I can not create any public project in any organizations of my Microsoft account.

What is the problem with creating a public project from Microsoft Account and how can I create one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution!

Go to **Organization Settings** *('Account Settings' for old UI of VSTS)* -> **Policy** -> **Security policies** and turn on the **Allow public projects**.

Answer (score 0):

Log in your VSTS account, and under settings|Policy

[image]